# Why are these graphs coming from 9-dimensional alternating trilinear forms so symmetric?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, multilinear-algebra

Let $\phi(x,y,z)$ be an alternating trilinear form on a space $V$ over a field $K$.

Let $u \in \mathbb{P}(V)$ be a projective point over $V$, then we say that the rank of $u$ is equal to the rank of the alternating bilinear form $\phi(u,.,.)$.

To the form $\phi$ we can associate a graph $G_\phi$, whose the vertices are the projective points in $\mathbb{P}(V)$, and two vertices $u,v$ share an edge if the linear form $\phi(u,v,.)$ is identically zero.

For Section 7 of [my work](https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/1528.pdf), I computed the restriction of these graphs to points of rank 4 for uniformly random $9$-dimensional alternating trilinear forms over finite fields of prime order $p$, and I stumbled on the following observation, which I cannot explain:

It seems that with high probability (the probability seems to go to 1 as $p$ grows), the graphs have Dihedral symmetry $D_{N}$, where $N$ is the number of points of rank 4. See, e.g., pictures below over GF(5).

Where does this come form? A guess would be that the automorphisms of the graph come from automorphisms of the trilinear form, but this is not the case. Usually, random forms $\phi$ have only a few (e.g. 2,3,4, or 6) automorphisms, but the graphs have much more automorphisms.

In fact, the automorphism group of the graph is not (always) a subgroup of $GL(n,K)$, because the rotation of the second picture below has order 29, but 29 does not divide $|GL(9,5)| = 2^{25}×3^5×5^{36}×7×11×13^2×19×31^3×71×313×829×19531$.

It is not so difficult to prove that the average (for random $\phi$) number of nodes in the graph is $q^2 + O(q)$, and the average number of edges is $q^3/2 + O(q^2)$ (Theorem 1 in my work). But the structure of the graph is still very mysterious to me. The pictures say that there is a free and transitive group action of the cyclic group of order $N$ on the $N$ points of rank $4$, but I have no idea what this group is and how it acts.

[image]

Comment: In case the link you supplied rots sometime in the next decade, your paper at the link is titled _Graph-theorethic Algorithms for the Alternating Trilinear Form Equivalence problem_

Comment: What is so special about rank 4 and dimension 9? Do you have similarly unexpected symmetries for other ranks/dimensions?

Comment: @MarcoGolla For $n \leq 8$ there is a huge number of automorphisms, just because $|GL(n,q)|\approx q^{n^2} > |ATF(n,q)| = q^{\binom{n}{3}}$, so these behave differently. For $n \geq 10$ I don't see the symmetries (although I didn't do a lot of experiments, because the graphs become very large and hard to compute). For $n=9$ I focus on rank 4, because that is whp the smallest rank that appears.

Comment: So it appears that rank 4 and dimension 9 is special somehow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The structure of the graph comes from a group structure on the set of rank-4 points!

Apparently you can associate an Abelian surface to alternating trilinear forms in dimension 9, e.g., see [The geometry of the Coble cubic and
orbital degeneracy loci](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02110007/document) by Vladimiro Benedetti, Laurent Manivel, Fabio Tanturri.

The points of the abelian surface are the rank-4 vectors of the alternating trilinear form, and after choosing an identity element, theorem 6.1 of Benedetti et al. allows you to compute the group law.

The rotations of the graphs I plotted are translations $X \mapsto X+Y$, and the reflections are just inversion $X \mapsto -X$. You get one inversion per choice of identity element.